# Error while upgrading to ng9/ivy with ng update

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

Error while upgrading to ng9/ivy with ng update

I have cleared out my node_modules folder before starting the run.

used:

```
npm install --no-save @angular/cli@^8.3.18
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --next
```

seems to fail on: experimental mdc-menu somewhere?

If I try to run after that, it doesn't load the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing ng-dragula fixed the issue for dragula